# UIButton in Custom TableViewCell not Changing Value when Selecting

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, uibutton, pfobject

Thanks to @jsetting32 I have a custom `UITableViewCell` complete with buttons at the bottom of the tableView.  However, when I am clicking those buttons, the value for the selectedState is not changing, making it a bit difficult for the end-user to tell if they have clicked it or not.

```
self.likeButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[self.likeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(didTapLikeButtonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.likeButton setTitle:@"Pray" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.likeButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.likeButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blueColor] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[[self.likeButton titleLabel] setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana" size:12.0f]];
[self.cellView addSubview:self.likeButton];
```

Comment: what do you mean clicked or not? You want the button to remember the like after you scroll up and down? This code is not enough to do that

Comment: You need to tell the button to remain selected if you want it to remain selected. Could you post your code from `didTapLikeButtonAction:`? This is all within your custom UITableViewCell class right?

Comment: @LyndseyScott I simply want the color or something of the UIButton to change WHILE the user still has their finger on it.  Right now, there is absolutely no change in behavior when their finger hits the button.  I just need a UI change in the button so they can tell if they pushed it or not.

Comment: @user717452 Oh. You mean *highlighted*. Change UIControlStateSelected to UIControlStateHighlighted.

Comment: You should handle this in your controller class that loads this cell since the delegate is the controller class. Also i recommend you don't change anything, just set the button properties for UIControlStateHighlighted. `[self.likeButton setTitleColor:[UIColor yellowColor forState:UIControlStateHighlighted]`

Answer (score 1):

Try `UIControlStateHighlighted` instead of `UIControlStateSelected`

```
[self.likeButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.likeButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blueColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

Answer (score 1):

So heres how I solve the button issue... There should already be a method within your custom cell that sets the like status... It is set like so

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cellIdentifier";

    if (indexPath.row == [self.objects count])
        return [self tableView:tableView cellForNextPageAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    PHChatCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[PHChatCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        [cell setDelegate:self];
    }

    [self setCellAttributesWithCell:cell withObject:[self.object objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] withIndexPath:indexPath];

    return cell;
}


- (void)setCellAttributesWithCell:(PHChatCell *)cell withObject:(PFObject *)object withIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (object) {
        [cell setChat:object];
        [cell setTag:indexPath.row];
        [cell.likeButton setTag:indexPath.row];

        if ([[PHCache sharedCache] attributesForMessage:object]) {
            [cell setLikeStatus:[[PHCache sharedCache] isMessageLikedByCurrentUser:object]];

            NSString *likeCount = [[[PHCache sharedCache] likeCountForMessage:object] description];
            cell.likeCount.text = ([likeCount isEqualToString:@"1"]) ?
            [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ like", likeCount] :
            [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ likes", likeCount];

            NSString *commentCount = [[[PHCache sharedCache] commentCountForMessage:object] description];
            cell.commentCount.text = ([commentCount isEqualToString:@"1"]) ?
            [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ comment", commentCount] :
            [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ comments", commentCount];
            return;
        }

        @synchronized(self) {
            // Put this in your init method
            // self.outstandingSectionHeadersQueries = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary]
            if (![self.outstandingSectionHeaderQueries objectForKey:@(indexPath.row)]) {
                PFQuery *query = [PHUtility queryForActivitiesOnMessage:object cachePolicy:kPFCachePolicyNetworkOnly];
                [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
                    @synchronized(self) {
                        [self.outstandingSectionHeaderQueries removeObjectForKey:@(indexPath.row)];

                        if (error) return;

                        NSMutableArray *likers = [NSMutableArray array];
                        NSMutableArray *commenters = [NSMutableArray array];

                        BOOL isLikedByCurrentUser = NO;

                        for (PFObject *activity in objects) {
                            if ([[activity objectForKey:kPHActivityTypeKey] isEqualToString:kPHActivityTypeLike] && [activity objectForKey:kPHActivityFromUserKey]) {
                                [likers addObject:[activity objectForKey:kPHActivityFromUserKey]];
                            } else if ([[activity objectForKey:kPHActivityTypeKey] isEqualToString:kPHActivityTypeComment] && [activity objectForKey:kPHActivityFromUserKey]) {
                                [commenters addObject:[activity objectForKey:kPHActivityFromUserKey]];
                            }

                            if ([[[activity objectForKey:kPHActivityFromUserKey] objectId] isEqualToString:[[PFUser currentUser] objectId]] &&
                                [[activity objectForKey:kPHActivityTypeKey] isEqualToString:kPHActivityTypeLike]) {
                                isLikedByCurrentUser = YES;
                            }
                        }

                        [[PHCache sharedCache] setAttributesForMessage:object likers:likers commenters:commenters likedByCurrentUser:isLikedByCurrentUser];

                        if (cell.tag != indexPath.row) return;

                        [cell setLikeStatus:[[PHCache sharedCache] isMessageLikedByCurrentUser:object]];

                        NSString *likeCount = [[[PHCache sharedCache] likeCountForMessage:object] description];
                        cell.likeCount.text = ([likeCount isEqualToString:@"1"]) ?
                        [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ like", likeCount] : [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ likes", likeCount];

                        NSString *commentCount = [[[PHCache sharedCache] commentCountForMessage:object] description];
                        cell.commentCount.text = ([commentCount isEqualToString:@"1"]) ?
                        [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ comment", commentCount] : [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ comments", commentCount];
                    }
                }];
            }
        }
    }
}


- (void)PHChatCell:(PHChatCell *)cell didTapLikeButton:(UIButton *)button chat:(PFObject *)chat
{
    // Disable the button so users cannot send duplicate requests
    [cell shouldEnableLikeButton:NO];

    //These are private interface properties to handle when the user wants to unlike the prayer
    //when the UIActionsheet is loaded
    self.chat = chat;
    self.likeButton = button;
    self.cell = cell;

    if (button.selected) {
        [[[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:@"Unlike" otherButtonTitles:nil] showInView:self.view];
        return;
    }

    BOOL liked = !button.selected;
    [cell setLikeStatus:liked];

    NSString *originalButtonTitle = button.titleLabel.text;
    NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [numberFormatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"]];

    NSNumber *likeCount = [numberFormatter numberFromString:button.titleLabel.text];
    [button setTitle:@"Liked" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
        [cell.likeImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ButtonLikeSelected.png"]];
        [cell.likeImage setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.5, 1.5)];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished){
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
            [cell.likeImage setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 1)];
        }];
    }];

    NSInteger checker = [[cell.likeCount text] integerValue] + 1;
    cell.likeCount.text = (checker == 1) ?
    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld like", (long)checker] :
    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld likes", (long)checker];
    likeCount = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[likeCount intValue] + 1];

    [[PHCache sharedCache] incrementLikerCountForMessage:chat];
    [[PHCache sharedCache] setMessageIsLikedByCurrentUser:chat liked:liked];
    [PHUtility likeMessageInBackground:chat block:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        PHChatCell *actualCell = (PHChatCell *)[self tableView:self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:button.tag inSection:0]];
        [actualCell shouldEnableLikeButton:YES];
        [actualCell setLikeStatus:succeeded];

        if (!succeeded) {
            [actualCell.likeButton setTitle:originalButtonTitle forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
    }];
}
#pragma mark - UIActionSheetDelegate
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == 0) {

        BOOL liked = !self.likeButton.selected;
        [self.cell setLikeStatus:liked];

        [self.likeButton setTitle:@"Like" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.cell.likeImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ButtonLike.png"]];

        NSInteger checker = [[self.cell.likeCount text] integerValue] - 1;
        self.cell.likeCount.text = (checker == 1) ?
        [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld like", (long)checker] :
        [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld likes", (long)checker];

        NSString *originalButtonTitle = self.likeButton.titleLabel.text;
        NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
        NSNumber *likeCount = [numberFormatter numberFromString:self.likeButton.titleLabel.text];
        likeCount = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[likeCount intValue] + 1];
        if ([likeCount intValue] > 0) {
            likeCount = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[likeCount intValue] - 1];
        }

        [[PHCache sharedCache] decrementLikerCountForMessage:self.chat];
        [[PHCache sharedCache] setMessageIsLikedByCurrentUser:self.chat liked:NO];
        [PHUtility unlikeMessageInBackground:self.chat block:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
            PHChatCell *actualCell = (PHChatCell *)[self tableView:self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:self.likeButton.tag inSection:0]];
            [actualCell shouldEnableLikeButton:YES];
            [actualCell setLikeStatus:!succeeded];

            if (!succeeded) {
                [actualCell.likeButton setTitle:originalButtonTitle forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            }
        }];
    }
}
```

Here is the query method used in the previous snippet of code (declared in PHUtility class) :

```
+ (PFQuery *)queryForActivitiesOnMessage:(PFObject *)message cachePolicy:(PFCachePolicy)cachePolicy {
    PFQuery *queryLikes = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:kPHActivityClassKey];
    [queryLikes whereKey:kPHActivityMessageKey equalTo:message];
    [queryLikes whereKey:kPHActivityTypeKey equalTo:kPHActivityTypeLike];

    PFQuery *queryComments = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:kPHActivityClassKey];
    [queryComments whereKey:kPHActivityMessageKey equalTo:message];
    [queryComments whereKey:kPHActivityTypeKey equalTo:kPHActivityTypeComment];

    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery orQueryWithSubqueries:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:queryLikes,queryComments,nil]];
    [query setCachePolicy:cachePolicy];
    [query includeKey:kPHActivityFromUserKey];
    [query includeKey:kPHActivityMessageKey];

    return query;
}
```

Here are the PHCache implementation ...

```
@interface PHCache()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSCache *cache;
- (void)setAttributes:(NSDictionary *)attributes forMessage:(PFObject *)message;
@end

@implementation PHCache
@synthesize cache;

#pragma mark - Initialization

+ (id)sharedCache {
    static dispatch_once_t pred = 0;
    __strong static id _sharedObject = nil;
    dispatch_once(&pred, ^{
        _sharedObject = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return _sharedObject;
}

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.cache = [[NSCache alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)clear {
    [self.cache removeAllObjects];
}
- (void)setAttributes:(NSDictionary *)attributes forMessage:(PFObject *)message {
    [self.cache setObject:attributes forKey:[self keyForMessage:message]];
}
- (NSString *)keyForMessage:(PFObject *)message {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"message_%@", [message objectId]];
}

#pragma mark - Global Chat
- (void)setAttributesForMessage:(PFObject *)message
                         likers:(NSArray *)likers
                     commenters:(NSArray *)commenters
             likedByCurrentUser:(BOOL)likedByCurrentUser {
    NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                [NSNumber numberWithBool:likedByCurrentUser],kPHMessageAttributesIsLikedByCurrentUserKey,
                                @([likers count]),kPHMessageAttributesLikeCountKey,
                                likers,kPHMessageAttributesLikersKey,
                                @([commenters count]),kPHMessageAttributesCommentCountKey,
                                commenters,kPHMessageAttributesCommentersKey,
                                nil];
    [self setAttributes:attributes forMessage:message];
}

- (NSDictionary *)attributesForMessage:(PFObject *)message {
    return [self.cache objectForKey:[self keyForMessage:message]];
}

- (NSNumber *)likeCountForMessage:(PFObject *)message {
    NSDictionary *attributes = [self attributesForMessage:message];
    if (attributes) {
        return [attributes objectForKey:kPHMessageAttributesLikeCountKey];
    }

    return [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];
}

- (NSNumber *)commentCountForMessage:(PFObject *)message {
    NSDictionary *attributes = [self attributesForMessage:message];
    if (attributes) {
        return [attributes objectForKey:kPHMessageAttributesCommentCountKey];
    }

    return [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];
}

- (NSArray *)likersForMessage:(PFObject *)message {
    NSDictionary *attributes = [self attributesForMessage:message];
    if (attributes) {
        return [attributes objectForKey:kPHMessageAttributesLikersKey];
    }

    return [NSArray array];
}

- (NSArray *)commentersForMessage:(PFObject *)message {
    NSDictionary *attributes = [self attributesForMessage:message];
    if (attributes) {
        return [attributes objectForKey:kPHMessageAttributesCommentersKey];
    }

    return [NSArray array];
}

- (void)setMessageIsLikedByCurrentUser:(PFObject *)message liked:(BOOL)liked {
    NSMutableDictionary *attributes = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:[self attributesForMessage:message]];
    [attributes setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:liked] forKey:kPHMessageAttributesIsLikedByCurrentUserKey];
    [self setAttributes:attributes forMessage:message];
}

- (BOOL)isMessageLikedByCurrentUser:(PFObject *)message {
    NSDictionary *attributes = [self attributesForMessage:message];
    if (attributes) {
        return [[attributes objectForKey:kPHMessageAttributesIsLikedByCurrentUserKey] boolValue];
    }

    return NO;
}

- (void)incrementLikerCountForMessage:(PFObject *)message {
    NSNumber *likerCount = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[[self likeCountForMessage:message] intValue] + 1];
    NSMutableDictionary *attributes = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:[self attributesForMessage:message]];
    [attributes setObject:likerCount forKey:kPHMessageAttributesLikeCountKey];
    [self setAttributes:attributes forMessage:message];
}

- (void)decrementLikerCountForMessage:(PFObject *)message {
    NSNumber *likerCount = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[[self likeCountForMessage:message] intValue] - 1];
    if ([likerCount intValue] < 0) {
        return;
    }
    NSMutableDictionary *attributes = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:[self attributesForMessage:message]];
    [attributes setObject:likerCount forKey:kPHMessageAttributesLikeCountKey];
    [self setAttributes:attributes forMessage:message];
}

- (void)incrementCommentCountForMessage:(PFObject *)message {
    NSNumber *commentCount = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[[self commentCountForMessage:message] intValue] + 1];
    NSMutableDictionary *attributes = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:[self attributesForMessage:message]];
    [attributes setObject:commentCount forKey:kPHMessageAttributesCommentCountKey];
    [self setAttributes:attributes forMessage:message];
}

- (void)decrementCommentCountForMessage:(PFObject *)message {
    NSNumber *commentCount = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[[self commentCountForMessage:message] intValue] - 1];
    if ([commentCount intValue] < 0) {
        return;
    }
    NSMutableDictionary *attributes = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:[self attributesForMessage:message]];
    [attributes setObject:commentCount forKey:kPHMessageAttributesCommentCountKey];
    [self setAttributes:attributes forMessage:message];
}

- (NSNumber *)messageCountForUser:(PFUser *)user {
    NSDictionary *attributes = [self attributesForUser:user];
    if (attributes) {
        NSNumber *photoCount = [attributes objectForKey:kPHUserAttributesMessageCountKey];
        if (photoCount) {
            return photoCount;
        }
    }

    return [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];
}

- (void)setMessageCount:(NSNumber *)count user:(PFUser *)user {
    NSMutableDictionary *attributes = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:[self attributesForUser:user]];
    [attributes setObject:count forKey:kPHUserAttributesMessageCountKey];
    [self setAttributes:attributes forUser:user];
}
```

Like I said in your previous post... It requires a hefty amount of code to make this feature 'optimal'... Reason for the cache object is to limit api requests to the servers. If the cell has been loaded, we're gonna check the cache to see if the attributes for the cell have been loaded, if it hasn't query to the server to get the attributes and set the cache to ensure we don't need to make an api request in the future...

All the variables starting with `kPH` are constants that you can declare on your own, or how you feel is sufficient... Like I said before, checking out the Anypic project and integrating the features into your app is best. Just copy over the PAPCache class and PAPUtility class over. Just make sure you read over the code to fully understand what is going on to get a better sense of how to integrate the code with yours, and to extend it to add more features to your app.

If you have any issues please feel free to post a comment.

Comment: Here is where the setting of the prayer button is done when the ViewController is loaded... Within the `setCellAttributesWithCell:withObject:withIndexPath`. If the cache object doesn't have the current cell's attributes loaded already, we query to the database to check to see if the CURRENT USER has tapped the prayer button or not, set the cells prayer button to prayed or not prayed, then set the cache object. I understand its a lot to think about but thats what happens when dealing with these kind of responsive features

Comment: I also recommend, create a Utility Class (filled with + methods to make your project cleaner) as well as a Cache Class (filled with - methods to access and set your NSCache object... I have done so for both apps I have and it really makes my life easier when coding

Answer (score 1):

i. While touching use UIControlStateHighlighted as suggested above.
ii. Keep a different color:
    Since you have a custom UITableViewCell, you should implement an IBAction and set your UIButton to this using

```
[self.likeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(select:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

in the .m file of your cell set:

```
-(IBAction)onSelectCellClicked:(id)sender {
   if(self.yourButton.selected) {
      self.yourButton.selected = NO;
    } else {
      self.yourButton.selected = YES;
    }
}
```

Now set the cell's delegate to self in cell for row after putting this in the cell's .h file:

```
@protocol CustomCellDelegate <NSObject>
@end

@interface CustomCell : UITableViewCell
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSObject<CustomCellDelegate>* delegate;

@end
```

And put  in the VC that is presenting the UITableView using the custom cell.

Answer (score 0):

you can just add this line into **'didTapLikeButtonAction'** :

```
self.likeButton.selected = !self.likeButton.selected;
```

once you change the selected state, the button will change its title color.

you may also want to add this line for a smoother effect:

```
[self.likeButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blueColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```